# Data not persisting on Docker - Windows 10 Volumes docker-compopse.yml

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, windows-10

Thanks for having a look at this.

I'm getting started with using Docker along Django and while trying to set up postgres to have its own volume in order to have data persisting after docker-compose down, it isn't saving at all.

Steps:

1. `docker-compose up -d`
2. `docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate`
3. `docker-compose exec web python manage.py createsuperuser`
4. check if all is fine at `/admin` and that user exists
5. `docker-compose down`

Then when running it back up:

1. `docker-compose up -d`
2. check `/admin` and have errors that are only resolved if I run step 2 and 3 above.

I have tried setting this env var as recommended by other posts but without success:

`COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`

The directory (full path) I am working on is also shared at the Docker/Settings/Resources/File Sharing area.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
    web:
        build: .
        command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
           - 8000:8000
        depends_on: 
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:11
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/postgres_data/
        environment: 
            - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

Comment: Does it also happen if you use `docker-compose stop` instead of `docker-compose down`?

Comment: After tweaking about I noticed that adding /data/ instead of /postgres_data/ at the end of the db volumes line but also removing the '_' (underscore) from 'postgres_data' (at both volumes sections) makes it work. I can compose down now and both the migrations and db users are saved. Thanks for the suggestion J.Scott. Appreciate it.

Comment: You could also try adding quotes: `'postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/postgres_data/'`

Comment: I have tried adding 'postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/postgres_data/' (with quotes) but it fails to save data. Also tried the docker-compose stop along with that method but it fails. The only way to have this working is adding the /data/. I had a look at this realpython.com tutorial (https://realpython.com/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/#docker-compose) and at the docker-compose.yml section it was followed the same standard (/data/) and further down it states that this 'data volume' is needed if you want data to persist. Thanks again J.Scott for all the help!